# Freebase - query media_common on book_edition to get /book/book?

Tags: freebase, mql

a complete beginner with freebase here, trying to understand how to make a query to find a `/book/book` by `/book_edition/media_common/cataloged_instance/isbn13`.

I tried this query and got this error: `Type /book/book_edition does not have property media_common`:

```
[{
  "type": "/book/book",
  "editions": [{
    "media_common": [{
      "cataloged_instance": [{
        "isbn13": "9780812519112" //example isbn13 from ender's game - https://www.freebase.com/m/04v8gr6
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "id": null
}]
```

EDIT: this is the query I used to get the deprecated ISBN field on book_edition

```
[{
  "type": "/book/book",
  "editions": [{
    "ISBN": "0312932081"
  }],
  "id": null
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is actually `/media_common/cataloged_instance/isbn13` which you can discover by exploring the schema.  Because it's from a different type than the expected type of `/book/book/editions` (which is `/book/book_edition` you need to use the fully qualified name.  Ditto for the author property I added to the query below.

```
[{
  "type": "/book/book",
  "editions": [{
    "/media_common/cataloged_instance/isbn13": "9780812519112"
  }],
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "/book/written_work/author": null
}]
```

without using the shorthand notation that allows us to drop type prefixes on property names, this query would look like:

```
[{
  "/book/book/editions": [{
    "/media_common/cataloged_instance/isbn13": "9780812519112"
  }],
  "/type/object/id": null,
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/book/written_work/author": null
}]
```

The expansion of the property names to their fully qualified versions gets done mechanically by the query processor without any real knowledge of the schema.  Conversely, graph traversal treats the property names as opaque strings.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it works. I would appreciate if you could explain why... how is the nested syntax I've used in the example different from doing it all as one key... (I also had `editions > media_common > cataloged_instance > isbn13`, I thought it does the same thing

Comment: You're confusing link/edge following (which is what nesting does) with property naming.  They're (mostly) unrelated to each other. The full name of the property is `/media_common/cataloged_instance/isbn13`.  There is no type `/book_edition' (it's `/book/book_edition') and the `isbn13` property is associated with the type `/media_common/cataloged_instance`.   For the purposes of graph traversal, the property name is just an opaque string with no structure.

Comment: Huh. I've used that syntax to query the regular ISBN value (which is on book_edition), looks like I still have lots to learn.  Thanks

Comment: If you post a link to a working query, I can try to explain how it differs from this example.

Comment: Tom, I put the query I used to get the ISBN in the OP. But while looking at it, I noticed that I actually only had one nested level for editions, so I guess I was wrong about what I was using

Comment: OK, no worries.  The only subtlety about the second query is that MQL knows that the "expected type" of things linked via `/book/book/editions` is `/book/book_edition`, so your `ISBN` is shorthand for `/book/book_edition/ISBN`